# Storing address in a small database program

Tags: c

I am writing a small program with a database organized with the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    char phone[12];
    char address[50];
} database;
```

When I ask to input all the values of one entry, I do it as below (the var save is 0 at the beginning of the program):

```
   if(option == 1)
    {
        printf("\nPlease input each of the following parameters separated by space: \n");
        printf("Firstname Lastname Phone Address: \n");
        scanf("%s %s %s %s", &list[save].fname, &list[save].lname, &list[save].phone, &list[save].address);
        save++;
        printf("\n\n!!!!! DONE !!!!!\n\n");
    }
```

The problem is, I want the last string input (address) to be able to store a complete sentence with spaces. When I input something like for example Andres Guerra +15551234 55555 AB Ave., UT. It will only save in list[save].address the 55555, the rest of the things stays stored for the next input, causing storage discrepancies.

How can I save in the address struct element a complete sentence with spaces included?

NOTE: I also tried making an additional scanf of %s with the address alone, but it did not work either.

If I use Country instead of Address, the program works fine.

Comment: Shortest way : use `;` as separator and `strok()` to split a big string.

Comment: Or use flex and bison

Comment: But definitely do not use scanf.  scanf is not suitable for anything but university exercises, and even there its applicability is questionable.

Comment: Well I am still a beginner, so I dont know what else to use instead of scanf, maybe gets is a good choice?

Comment: If you must use scanf, make sure you specify the maximum length of the string you'll accept. Otherwise you're at risk for buffer overrun.  For example, since `fname` is `char[20]`, use `scanf("%19s", x.fname)`. This will store at most 19 characters into `fname`, leaving room for a terminating `\0`.

Comment: @AndresGuerra: Using `gets()` is an extremely bad choice; using `fgets()` might well be a sensible choice, possibly coupled with `sscanf()`.  It is unfortunate that `scanf()` is taught so early because although trivial cases are workable, it is hard to use correctly. For example, you might use `"… %49[^\n]"` to read up to 49 non-newline characters as the address field (the fiftieth character will be used for the null, of course). But that's not trivial, and the space before it is crucial, and the newline is left in the input stream which can cause confusion if you're using `scanf()` after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
scanf("%s %s %s %49[0-9a-zA-Z ]", 
  &list[save].fname, 
  &list[save].lname, 
  &list[save].phone, 
  &list[save].address
);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The trailing `s` in `"%s %s %s %49[0-9a-zA-Z ]s"` is spurious; `%[…]` is a complete conversion specification and the `s` matches a literal `s` (but will only do so if preceded by exactly 49 characters that match the scan-set).  You'll never know that the `s` is not matched when it is the last character in format string, but add, for example, a number conversion after it and you'll never get all the data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for pointing out trailing `s`. Corrected.

Comment: @Amit. Thank you for your suggestion, it works. 

There is still one thing however, as I can notice on the code, it only allows me to input characters from a-z, A-Z, 0-9. What about characters such as . or - or # or , ? I would appreciate if you could point out which range I could add. or I can leave the range with the whole ASCII table for example?

This is, of course, to allow the program to input addresses such as:  Morgan St. # 31-106 as an example.

Comment: @AndresGuerra: You can try adding any character in `[0-9a-zA-Z #?]`